# "Enable Live Reload" and Enable Hot Reloading" options missing from action sheet after Shake Gesture

Tags: react-native

When selecting the Simulator's "Shake" gesture to bring up the Reload/Inspector/Monitor options, the "Enable Live Reload" and "Enable Hot Reloading" options are missing.

I had an old version running, along with a new instance (same code). The new instances do not show the most useful options.

> react-native info

produces:

`React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.4
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4278U CPU @ 2.60GHz
      Memory: 84.52 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 11.4.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.12.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.5.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 23, 25, 26, 27, 28
        Build Tools: 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.3
        System Images: android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
      Xcode: 10.2/10E125 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: ^16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
      react-native: ^0.56.1 => 0.56.1 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7`

So far I have removed the iOS build directory and reset everything:

> rm -rf ios/build  &&  watchman watch-del-all  &&   npm start -- --reset-cache

and re-ran yarn,

> yarn start --reset-cache

rebooted, all to no avail.

I am using React Native 0.56.1

I've included a screen shot of an old simulator window that was left open, and a new instance, using the same code base, on the right.

[image]

Comment: Did you resolve this?  If so, how?

Comment: @JoshuaKifer, unfortunately, this lingered on for a while. I tried what similar questions attempted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689958/cannot-use-live-reload-hot-reload-on-a-device). Ultimately, I re-wiped it, re-pulled the code from git-hub and upgraded about 3 versions (it persisted in several versions, until about 0.60).

Comment: Thanks.  It mysteriously just fixed itself for me.

Answer (score 1):

If Hot Reload or Live Reload Options are missing it is due to this as mentioned in the react-native blog

> When we asked the React Native community about common pain points, one of the top answers was that the “hot reloading” feature was broken. It didn’t work reliably for function components, often failed to update the screen, and wasn’t resilient to typos and mistakes.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/09/18/version-0.61

Comment: While I don't think that answers the question directly, it shows the new and better way to handle this. Thanks for the input.